# how to show the coordinate bond in avogadro?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I have this structure figure 1, I want to visualize by Avogadro, but the shape is not as I want like in figure 2 where I used Molden, so how can I make Avogadro draw the coordinate bonds.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

Comment: What Avogadro version? What format are working with (I hope it's not `*.xyz`)? Could you post the file content? Have you tried to [manually connect atoms](https://avogadro.cc/docs/getting-started/drawing-molecules/)? And why [tag:organic-chemistry] tag?

Comment: Sorry for Tag organic chemistry
the version is 1.2.0
it is not xyz file, it is different (file from CASPT2 Calculation) as I want to visualize the molecular orbital.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first representation is *ball and stick*, because atoms represented as spheres, and bonds in rod-like shape.  The lower illustration is an example of *stick*, where atoms and bonds share the visualization as a stick. The question is not limited to the visualization of coordination compounds, nor the file type read by the program. If you use Avogadro 1.2.0 (e.g., from Linux Xubuntu 18.04 LTS)* then

- go Settings -> Toolbars -> Tools to enable the relevant toolbar which show a button «Display settings»
- a click on this button opens a new GUI.  Here *deselect* the entry «Ball and Stick», and select instead «Stick».  With default parameters (*via* the small wrench symbol at the right hand side you may adjust them), having both options enabled will yield an image like using «Ball and Stick» only.

[image]

*) You may be interested to join the [Avogadro discourse](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) to stay informed about recent developments of the program (e.g., announced [release 1.9.4](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/avogadro-1-94-released/3523) a few days ago, entering [debichem](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/avogadro); or a glimpse about an improved Avogadro2 anticipated for fall 2021 [here](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/t/highlight-atoms-by-inputing-atom-numbers/3545/7)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still have the same problem but ok, I will complete working with molden or gmolden.

Comment: For files types anticipated to be read, Jmol has lists ([example](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/File_formats/Coordinates)) and test files ([repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Jmol-datafiles/)). I don't know CASPT2 you mentioned, nor if there a similar public repository of a test output (atom location + orbital's information).